# Autocompletetextview dropdown displayed over keyboard

Tags: android, dropdown, android-softkeyboard, autocompletetextview

I am trying to create an autocompletetextview at the bottom of a bottomsheet inside an activity.I want the dropdown to **open above the autocompletetextview**.

When keyboard is hidden it is displayed in the correct manner.-> [Desired dropdown position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0zeS.png)

But when keyboard appears this dropdown appears **over the keyboard**. -> [Problematic dropdown position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUmzU.png)

Here is my xml code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_select_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="@string/select_date_range"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_start_date"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/from_date"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar_24"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/til_end_date"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_select_date"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_start_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_end_date"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/end_date"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_calendar_24"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
        app:endIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/til_start_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_select_date"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/tiet_end_date"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_end_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_show_archived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/show_archived_calls"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/seperator1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_show_archived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/txt_show_archived"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/txt_show_archived" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seperator2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_show_archived" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_select_members"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/select_team_members"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/seperator2">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/actv_members"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:text="@string/all_team_members"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_apply"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/apply"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_select_members" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_clear"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/clear_filters"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_filter_apply"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_select_members" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_filter"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_filter_clear"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_select_members" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I have already tried:

- adjustResize|adjustPan in manifest
- adding adjust resize in window programatically
- decreasing dropdown height
- dropDownVerticalOffset
- dropDownAnchor

Comment: Try to add a complete layout in ScrollView and `adjustPan` only in manifest.

Comment: @PraveshSingh, did you manage to solve the problem? I have the same problem and can't manage it

Comment: @АндрійХ I have added the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the bottom sheet must be fully expanded in order to prevent hiding behind the keyboard for small screens.You need to explicity set the state to expanded. One can solve this problem by adding the following code :

```
// open bottom sheet as fully expanded to prevent hiding behind keyboard in small screens
        Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            BottomSheetDialog btmShtDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = btmShtDialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheet != null) {
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });
```